# Record type pattern matching in Ocaml

Tags: types, pattern-matching, ocaml, record

I'm trying to use pattern matching to write a calculator application.

Two major types defined as below:

```
type key = Plus | Minus | Multi | Div | Equals | Digit of int;;

type state = {
    lcd: int; (* last computation done *)
    lka: key; (* last key actived *)
    loa: key; (* last operation actived *)
    vpr: int (* value print on the screen *)
};;

let print_state s =
    match s with
     state (a,_,_,d) -> print_int a; //Here has the compile error
                print_newline();
                print_int d;
                    print_newline();;
```

However, if I have a state like:

```
let initial_state = { lcd=0; lka=Equals; loa=Equals; vpr=0 } ;;
```

Then when I invoke the function:

```
print_state initial_state;;
```

It will have the compile error. Anyone can tell what's the reason for unsuccessful compilation. Thanks in adv.

```
Error: Syntax error
unexpected token "("
```

Comment: But why are you pattern matching on records? To get the `lcd` out of `initial_state`, use `initial_state.lcd`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A record pattern looks like a record:

```
match s with
| { lcd = a; vpr = d; _ } -> (* Expression *)
```

Comment: @yjasrc In modern OCaml you can also skip the `=` part if you name the variable in the same way as the label: `match s with {lcd; vpr; _ } -> print_int lcd; print_int vpr`.

Comment: To add to luksatfi's comment, it's also not necessary to have a match statement at all. `let print_state {lcd; vpr; _} = ...` should be enough.

Comment: I tried the other way around (`{a = lcd...`) before googling this, which seems more natural to me, but hey. At least there *is* a way. Thanks for the answer, and thanks to @yjasrc for asking the question.

Comment: In my case, I had a match statement because it was a result type. I don't like unnamed vars, so I prefer `{lcd; vpr; lka = _lka; loa = _loa;}` It might be different if there are many fields, but if there are only a handful, it's more interesting to see what else is available when reading the code, even if the fields are not currently used.