# How to extract information from a record in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, match, records

I have a type record:

```
type record = { first : string; second : string list; third : string }
```

I want to extract data from it using match...How would I do that?..

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Record type pattern matching in Ocaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173690/record-type-pattern-matching-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 6):

You can match the whole record:

```
match my_record with
| { first = "something"; } -> do_something
| { second = hd :: tl; third = "something else"; } -> do_something_else
(* ... *)
```

or target specific fields in it with the dot notation:

```
match my_record.second with
| hd :: tl -> do_something
(* ... *)
```

It is also possible to destructure a record in a function with a syntactic shortcut called field punning:

```
let fun_example { first; third; _ } =
  "This is first: " ^ first ^ " and this is third: " ^ third
```

or by providing aliases for the fields:

```
let fun_example_2 { first = f; third = t; _ } =
  "This is first: " ^ f ^ " and this is third: " ^ t
```

The underscore `; _` in the pattern is used to tell the compiler it shouldn't worry about incomplete matches when the `#warnings "+9"` directive is turned on in the toplevel. It may be omitted depending on your style.

For more intricate details please refer to RWO, there's [a great chapter on records](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/records.html)!