# Record pattern matching

Tags: f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml, record

According to this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17174120/7821462), in F# and OCaml I need to use underscore for discarding the rest of the record. However, why does the `handle'` function work but `handle` function doesn't?

```
type Type = Type of int

type Entity =
    { type' : Type
      foo : string }

let handle entities =
    match entities with
    | {type' = Type i; _ }::entites -> ()
    | [] -> ()

let handle' entities =
    match entities with
    | {type' = Type i }::entites -> ()
    | [] -> ()
```

Comment: Maybe it is 'just' an incompatibility between OCaml and F#. Out of curiosity, how did you get to the conclusion that it is supposed to work in F#? (I'm not saying that the incompatibility is a good thing; just that it might be a thing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably not helpful to treat OCaml and F# as the same language. Your code is invalid OCaml for several reasons.

But you're right, the `_` is not necessary in OCaml. It is useful if you want to get a warning for incomplete record patterns. If you mark intentionally incomplete record patterns with `_` and turn on warning 9, then record patterns without `_` will be flagged if they don't specify all the fields of the record.

```
$ rlwrap ocaml -w +9
        OCaml version 4.03.0

# type t = { a: int; b: string};;
type t = { a : int; b : string; }
# let f {a = n} = n;;
Warning 9: the following labels are not bound in this record pattern:
b
Either bind these labels explicitly or add '; _' to the pattern.
val f : t -> int = <fun>
```

It was fairly hard to find the documentation for this. You can find it in [Section 7.7](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.03/extn.html#sec226) of the OCaml manual. It's listed specifically as a language extension.