# Ambiguity with pattern matching records

Tags: ocaml

I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173690/record-type-pattern-matching-in-ocaml) that it's possible to use pattern matching with records. However, I've noticed that I'm having trouble trying to match different types of records.

My goal in this example is to be able to distinguish between different records. I'm given a record that I'm not entirely sure which type it is, and I'm trying to figure it out using pattern matching.

Here's a simplified example:

```
module IceCream = struct
  type t = {
    temperature: float;
    toppings: string list;
  }
end

module Candy = struct
  type t = {
    flavour: string;
    colour: string;
    volume: int;
  }
end


(* Could be Candy or IceCream *)
let example =
  { Candy.
    flavour = "mint";
    colour = "green";
    volume = 10 }

let printFavoriteTreat treat = match treat with
  | { Candy.
      flavour = "mint";
      colour;
      volume } -> "It's Candy"
  | { IceCream.
      temperature;
      toppings } -> "It's IceCream"


let () = printFavoriteTreat example
```

When I try to build this file, I get:

```
Error: The field IceCream.temperature belongs to the record type IceCream.t
       but a field was expected belonging to the record type Candy.t
```

Is doing something like this possible?

Comment: Pattern matching on different types isn't possible, unless they're embedded in a sum type (also called variant type, algebraic datatype, discriminated union).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm given a record that I'm not entirely sure which type it is, and I'm trying to figure it out using pattern matching.

That is not possible. Types exist only at compile time, so checking what type it is at runtime is not possible.

In other words, in a valid program you can put a type annotation on every expression (in most cases you do not have to do that, though, thanks to type inference). If you cannot do that then you should design your program differently, such as using a sum type as others have suggested - in that case both values will have the same type (at compile time) but a different constructor (at run time).

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by Pierre is great, but the example not so much. (I've always hated examples named `a`, `b`...)

So, as Pierre suggests, you could define your types like this:

```
type ice_cream = {
  temperature: float;
  toppings: string
}

type candy = {
  flavor: string;
  color: string;
  volume: int
}
```

Then, you can define a type `treat` as a [variant](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/variants.html) of these two types:

```
type treat =
| Candy of candy
| IceCream of ice_cream
```

Then, using pattern-matching:

```
let print_favorite_treat = function
| Candy _ -> print_endline "You love candy!"
| IceCream _ -> print_endline "You love ice cream!"
```

Comment: The very fact that the function is called `print_favorite_treat` is a great hint that some kind of `treat` type is needed. :)

Comment: Ah I was hoping I could avoid variants but it looks like you can't match records the way I was trying to, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: You need a type that can be **either** a `candy` **or** an `ice_cream`. This is the typical use-case for variants. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match against to different types without using variant types.

The module syntax you are using cannot help,  as module just structure the code. You could have defined the following types :

```
type a = {
     temperature: float;
     toppings: string list;
  }

type b =  {
    flavour: string;
    colour: string;
    volume: int;
  }
```

But the results would be the same.

The way to disambiguate is to use variant types (or union type which is not described in the example below) :

```
let printFavoriteTreat treat = match treat with
  | `A{ Candy.
      flavour = "mint";
      colour;
      volume } -> "It's Candy"
  | `B { IceCream.
      temperature;
      toppings } -> "It's IceCream"
;;
```

And

```
let () = printFavoriteTreat (`A example)
```

Comment: You should probably use \`Candy instead of \`A and \`IceCream instead of \`B. And explain why a polymorphic variant (+ include `| _ -> "I don't know that treat"`) instead of a normal one.